# What is this form or syntax called in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the codebase I'm working on, there is a line that takes the following form:

```
    const {key1: value1, key2:value2} = name
```

What's with the left to right assignment? Doesn't `=` work right to left?

Comment: This is really _three_ separate questions with _three_ separate answers. It smells very much like a homework question.

Comment: Take a look at [Object_destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). `//***` is for commenting the code

Comment: Not homework, just bad question asking on my part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can the variable `name` be redefined?

It isn't.

> What's with the left to right assignment? Doesn't = work right to left?

Yes, and that's what's happening here. That's [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). This one line:

```
const {key1: value1, key2:value2} = name
```

is the equivalent of this:

```
const value1 = name.key1;
const value2 = name.key2;
```

You're quite right that it looks like an object being assigned to a variable, but in reverse. That's intentional. When you do:

```
const x = {a: 1, b: 2};
```

you're creating an object (putting together a structure) and assigning it to `x`. When you do:

```
const {a: vara, b: varb} = x;
```

you're *destructuring* (taking a structure apart) the object on the right into the targets (`vara` and `varb`) on the left. The syntax for this is **identical**, just reversed. Both forms also have a shorthand version:

```
const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const x = {a, b};
```

creates an object with `a` and `b` properties (with the values from the `a` and `b` in-scope identifiers). This;

```
const {a, b} = x;
```

takes `a` and `b` properties from `x` and uses it to set the value of the constants `a` and `b`.

I should note that nothing about destructuring is tied to `let` or `const` (or `var`). Just like you can use any in-scope variable or a property to provide the value for an object property when creating an object, you can do the same when destructuring. Because object destructuring starts with `{`, if you're not doing it in an expression you need to put a `(` in front of it so the `{` doesn't look like the beginning of a block:

```js
const x = {a: 1, b: 2};
let a, b;

({a, b} = x);
console.log(a, b); // 1 2

const y = {};

({a: y.ayyy, b: y.beee} = x);
console.log(y); // {ayyy: 1, beee: 2}
```

> what `name` is referenced in the line marked ***? The one initially passed or the object created?

There is no object created in that code. (Well, the arrow function is an object, and there are behind-the-scenes specification-level objects like the lexical environment, but...)

It's impossible to say what `name` is in the line you've marked because that's a syntax error, the `function` keyword starts a function declaration that's never finished. If by `function(name)` you meant `someFunction(name)`, it would be the `name` passed into the arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

1. How can the variable name be redefined? 
   Use normal JS syntax: let newName = name
2. What's with the left to right assignment? Doesn't = work right to left?
   Assignment is done from right to left. The syntax is object destructuring.
   You can learn about it here:
   https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/
3. what name is referenced in the line marked ***? The one initially passed or the object created?
   No new object is created in the code. 'name' refers to the original passed object.

Comment: It's usually best to set the right formatting on code text (also show code best practices). For instance:  

> 1. How can the variable name be redefined? Use normal JS syntax: `let newName = name;`

Comment: Generally, apply proper formatting to your submissions so it's easy to differentiate between regular text and source text or something you want to highlight. A good example is your **Item 3**

> What name is referenced in the line marked `***`? Is this the one initially passed or the object created? No new object is created in the code. `name` refers to the original passed object.